# Oracle Apex - Download CSV did not produces report

Tags: csv, plsql, download, report

I am writing a little webapp using Oracle Apex online ( apex.oracle.com ), I am having a problem with downloading reports as CSV file in the Action Menu.

On my Apex page I have an interactive report and 2 page items (P7_DATA_IN and P7_DATA_OUT). There's also a button named "Search" that fire the report.
Query for interactive report's source is :

```
SELECT  "DATA","CHG",SUM("BOX1"+"BOX2"+"BOX3")
FROM    "REQUESTS"    
WHERE   "DATA" BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P7_DATA_IN,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:P7_DATA_OUT,'DD-MON-YYYY')    
GROUP BY "CHG", "DATA", "CMA"
```

Clicking on Search button, report is displayed with correct rows, filtered second date.

**The problem:** When I select Actions -> Download -> CSV, download does not start, no popup given and page reset to blank. Same happen with xls or pdf format.

I already read similar questions here but all solutions given did not solve my problem, also tryed to move to Apex 4.1 and problem remains.
Just with classic report all works well .

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.